# What is the propre way to include jQuery UI Datepicker's CSS in plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I was looking for a datepicker, I read in another question's answer that jQuery UI's DatePicker is included in WordPress.

To make it work I needed to add in script inclusions

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
```

But now it's missing .css,

I tried to add this in styles inclusions

wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-datepicker');

but it didn't work.

In the WordPress I'm working on, I found however thousands of references for datepicker.
In the end I'm using this for now:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', plugin_dir_url(__DIR__) . 'jetpack/modules/contact-form/css/jquery-ui-datepicker.css' );
```

But I feel like there must be a more "WordPress-native" syntax which I'd like to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is fine. WordPress doesn't include CSS for the jQuery UI components, so you need to include it yourself. This is what Jetpack has done, and it's why you're able to load it from there. However this means that your plugin is dependent on Jetpack. Ideally you'd download the CSS (you can get it [here](http://jqueryui.com/download/)) yourself and include it in your own plugin/theme, and enqueue it from there.

Comment: Yes, in that case I will include the CSS in my plug-in, I expected WordPress to come with the CSS since it seems it comes with the JS.